# problem with google chrome and fileinput

Tags: google-chrome, file-io

We have a web site where a user can upload their resume.  If they upload it in any browser it works fine.  If they do NOT upload a document it works fine in all browsers but google chrome.  We have a server side vb dll that captures the form contents and any files uploaded are stored in a dictionary object which the processing page then queries.  In chrome our dll is reporting that there one file is uploaded when you don't actually upload anything.  Again, other browsers don't do this so I'm not sure what's going on.  Has anyone seen behavior like this and if so, is there a fix?  Thanks.

Comment: what you are using .net or java

Comment: it's old school asp pages  with a vb dll that captures the uploaded data

Comment: to test this go to http://employment.topechelon.com/platinum/upload_start.html and just click submit without uploading anything.  on the next page it writes out the filesize of what it received.  in chrome it writes out 61 for each empty file for me.  in IE I get an error since nothing was uploaded.  any ideas why?

Comment: and by filesize I mean lenb of the data that was sent.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my ASP project, where the HTTP header is handled by a VB function like [this](http://www.interattiva.net/mailattachment.asp). I wrote this simple form and I analyzed the HTTP header sent to the web server:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <p><input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send" /></p>
</form>
```

If the input file is empty and the user click "Send", all browsers (except Chrome) sends this HTTP header:

```
-----------------------------11538186919912
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename=""
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


-----------------------------11538186919912
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="send"

Send
-----------------------------11538186919912--
```

Google Chrome, instead, sends this HTTP header:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryD4c5HZchlBudkIaQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename=""


------WebKitFormBoundaryD4c5HZchlBudkIaQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="send"

Send
------WebKitFormBoundaryD4c5HZchlBudkIaQ--
```

Google Chrome, if the input file is empty, don't sends the "Content-Type" field. This is the only difference. Probably, as in my project, this difference can cause errors in your DLL.

I hope I have helped you, sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome (up to at least 8.0.552.215) has issues with content types of files. For me, it was if the file did not have an extension.

See: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6800

Note: I'm using struts 2.0.14 with the FileUploadInterceptor (uses ServletFileUpload and JakataMultipartRequest)